# Do I have to override python's list functions?

Tags: python, list, inheritance, overriding

I have a class `DataSet` that inherits from python's `list` class:

```
class DataSet(list):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(DataSet, self).__init__(*args)
```

Now I can create an instance of this class and print the type.

```
data = DataSet([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
print(type(data))
>>> <class 'DataSet'>
```

However, when I want to take for example a subset of this `DataSet` and I print the type, I get:

```
data2 = data[2:4]
print(type(data2))
>>> <class 'list'>
```

This happens because I have not overridden the `__getitem__` method of `list`. I know python's `list` class has a lot of methods that can be overridden in order to use them, but I am a programmer and the only thing I want to do is for all these methods that normally return an instance of type `list` now return that instance of type `DataSet`. Is there a method to achieve this, without overriding all these functions? Or do I have to override all these methods manually?

Comment: Yes, you do have to do it manually, but why inherit from `list` at all?

Comment: Do you plan to add anything meaningful to _your_ DataSet? Currently I see no benefit of wrapping lists that way. Inheriting lists (_IsA_) might not bee the way to go, maybe a list as internal member (_HasA_) would be better way to model your concerns. Or you could go with toolingmethods that work on lists.

Comment: Yes I am planning on doing meaningful things to `DataSet`. More specifically, I want to use it to contain instances of my own class `DataPoint`, which consists of a timestamp and a value. `DataSet` contains methods to do easily calculations with this `DataPoint` class, like Euler differentiation. I thought that inheriting the list class would work, because it has all those built in methods, but now I have to override them eventually, so perhaps HasA works better in this case.

Comment: Why don't you inherit from `collections.UserList` which is pretty much designed for avoiding to inherit directly from `list`, which has all kinds of surprising side effects. I think this should also solve your `type` problem.

Comment: You should generally prefer composition over inheritance.

Answer (score -1):

What you asking for is not impossible.it easy to iterate over all functions that return the array and change the output to what you want using a decorator. if you study the function and work on them manually you will learn more.

```
class DataSet(list):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(DataSet, self).__init__(*args)
#that where we must use decorator and loop over all builin functions
def  DataSet_evo(func):
    
    from inspect import signature
    
    def new_func(*args):
     res=func(*args)   
     if type(res)==type([])  :
      return DataSet(res)
     else:
      return res  #for example pop() it return element so it will throw eror as it not list 
         
   
    return new_func

for i in dir(DataSet):
 if i not in ["__init__","__class__"]:   
  try:   
   line="DataSet."+i+"="+"DataSet_evo(list."+i+")"   
   exec(line)
  except:
     pass# for handling .__class__ in dir
   
data = DataSet([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
print(type(data))        
data2 = data[2:4]
print(type(data2))
```

***Happy coding***